# What is an Imam, is he simply the leader of the jamaat?

Tags: salat

In the Sunni tradition, what exactly is the role of an Imam?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the literal meanings of the word "Imam"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51656/whats-the-literal-meanings-of-the-word-imam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *Imaam* in Arabic means a guide.  Its relevance changes depending on the context of the word being used.

If we're discussing prayer, it would mean someone who leads the prayer.  If we're discussing governing, it would mean the leader of the state.  But the role is to be the guide and lead.

The Prophet Mohammed used *Imaam* in these contexts.

Answer (score -5):

Imam have many roles : 
 praying
 answer of muslim question about different subjects in islam 
 make lecons
and more

source : www.islamweb.net 
also my reallife (i'm Muslim )

Comment: Welcome to islam stackexchange. Feel free to read [faq](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) to get you started. Here, islam stackexchange community expects answers to be supported by citations/resources. You can see highly upvoted answers to see what kind of answers the community appreciates. You can edit this answer in case you want to improve it.

Comment: We do not mean to offend anyone here, but you must understand that here we require that an answers has citations to back it up, make it stronger, and raise it's quality.  You have a good answer, you just need to put more detail, and give exact citations either from a reliable book or site, we pray you understand.

Comment: Allright  , thank you for your advice  and i will apply it :)