# What are the qualities an imam must have?

Tags: sunni, imam-khatib

What are the qualities an imam must have. Is there any specific qualities which an imam must have to be so.

And is it possible to force someone to be imam or someone becomes imam while other people are not liking it. What islam says in both of these situations too.
**(Sunni- With complete references please.)**

Comment: See also: "[What is an Imam, is he simply the leader of the jamaat?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5673/9123)" and "[How to be a proper Imam in a congregation of fardhu correctly? (Leading of Prayers)](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16969/9123)".

Comment: Thankyou but these does not answer my question.

Comment: Imam of what? It matters on the situation.

Comment: Imam of what? i meant imam which can lead prayer.